# why network interface has no Major number and minor number

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

guys
I am learning Linux Device Drivers.I have a question when reading below

"Since there is no equivalent of major and minor numbers for network interfaces, a network driver does not request such a number"

so could you please tell me why network interface has no major number or minor number by design?

Thanks

Comment: There are several ABIs between Linux kernel and user space. One of them is **netlink**, which is used for network devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Major and minor numbers are used by *character devices* or *block devices*, and this implies that the user interacts with these devices by reading from and writing to special *files* (*nodes*), so a *node* may be created using the two numbers (*major* determines the device driver whilst *minor* is to specify a particular device managed by the driver).

Network drivers don't need the numbers since the *approach* (or *design*, as you say) of accessing network adapters doesn't assume their representation as files or nodes. Instead, the concept of *network interfaces* is used. And you typically make use of these network interfaces by means of *socket API* (say, Berkeley sockets), and such a kernel subsystem as *network stack* is involved here as an intermediate agent between your application and the network driver. There is no read/write access through *files*.

Comment: "Major and minor numbers are used by character devices" - not just character devices. E.g. block devices use them too.